# Adding custom property to Client Side Entity class

Tags: entity-framework

I need to add a custom property to an Entity Framework class, however when I do I get the "The property name XXX specified for type XXX is not valid." error.  Is there some attribute I can give the property so it is ignored and not mapped to anything?

Edit:  If I add a custom property, as per Martin's example below, then the following code will raise the above error at the SaveChanges call.

```
MyEntities svc = new MyEntities(url);
MyEntity ent = new MyEntity();
ent.MyField = "Hello, world";
svc.AddMyEntity(ent);
svc.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What is the type of exception thrown? What happens if you delete your custom property? What if you rename it?

Comment: I get a System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException (An error occurred while processing this request.), and inside that a System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException (The property name XXX specified for type XXX is not valid.).  If I delete my custom property, or make it a function, it all works fine.  If its a different name, the same problem occurs.

Comment: I can't be the only person trying to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:
[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/b7a9e01d-c5c2-4478-8f01-00f7f6e0f75f](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7a9e01d-c5c2-4478-8f01-00f7f6e0f75f/data-services-client-exception-on-savechanges-when-processing-nonpersistent-properties-on-client?forum=adodotnetdataservices)

Edit:
[A better link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/phaniraj/customizing-serialization-of-entities-in-the-ado-net-data-services-client-library) describes the final compact answer of Adding an Attribute to prevent serialization of the Entity when sending to the Service.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a property in code:

```
public partial class MyEntity {
  public String MyCustomProperty {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

The Entity Framework generate partial classes enabling you to customize the generated class.

Also, to comment on your code I think should change it to something like this:

```
MyEntities svc = new MyEntities(url);
// Create MyEntity using the factory method.
MyEntity ent = MyEntities.CreateMyEntity(...);
ent.MyField = "Hello, world";
svc.AddMyEntity(ent);
svc.SaveChanges();
```

This will ensure that your entity is properly initialized.

Comment: That's what I have done but that would cause me to receive the above error when using the MyEntity class.

Comment: Can you clarify when you get the error? During validation of you model, when you compile, or at run-time?

Comment: When I try to use the object to update the database, eg:

MyEntities svc = new MyEntities(url);
MyEntity ent = new MyEntity();
ent.MyField = "Hello, world";
svc.AddMyEntity(ent);
svc.SaveChanges();

I get an exception on SaveChanges.